# How do I set the path to the build.xml file in a Jenkins ant build from an environment variable on Windows

Tags: windows, ant, jenkins, environment-variables

I am running an ant build in Windows from Jenkins and wish to pass the path to the build.xml file in an environment variable.  I am using the envinject plugin to do so.  I wish to set the variable on the project under "Prepare an environment for the run"->"Properties Content":

```
ANTBUILDDIR=C:\some\directory\here
```

Then in the ant build properties I set:

```
"Build File": %ANTBUILDDIR%\build.xml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `$ANTBUILDDIR/TheBuildFile.xml` as Jenkins configuration follows Unix shell variable expansion syntax.